# Running scrapy splash with proxies

Tags: proxy, scrapy, splash-screen

I am using proxy in scrapy splash, but I get 502 proxy all the time, it troubles me several days.

my downloadmiddleware:

```
class ABProxyMiddleware(HttpProxyMiddleware):
""" 阿布云ip代理配置 """
proxyAuth = "Basic " + base64.urlsafe_b64encode(
    bytes((settings['PROXY_USER'] + ":" + settings['PROXY_PASS']), "ascii")).decode("utf-8")

def process_request(self, request, spider):
    request.meta['splash']['args']['proxy'] = settings['PROXY_SERVER']
    request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = self.proxyAuth
```

my requests:

```
yield SplashRequest(url= 'http://www.qidian.com/all?chanId=4&subCateId=130&orderId=&style=1&pageSize=20&siteid=1&pubflag=0&hiddenField=0&page=' + str(
                i),callback=self.book_parse, endpoint='render.html')
```

my settings:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
'tempScrapy.middlewares.ABProxyMiddleware': 100,
```

}

I am sure that all the setting about proxy is right,and the proxy is valid,for it will be successful with out splash

Comment: why do you need to use  a proxy server?

Comment: my aim url is not http://www.qidian.com，I just use it for a try，my aim url restict IP access times so I must use a proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, you're sending the proxy authentication headers to the Splash server:

```
+-------------+
| Your spider |
+------+------+
       |
       | Proxy Authentication
       v
+------+-------+
|   Splash     |
+------+-------+
       |
       |
       v
+------+-------+
| Proxy server |
+------+-------+
       |
       |
       v
+------+-------+
| Target site  |
+--------------+
```

The Splash server would simply ignore the proxy authentication header you send, and thus the proxy server would reject your request due to unsuccessful authentication.

The right thing to do is to have Splash send the proxy authentication header:

```
+-------------+
| Your spider |
+------+------+
       |
       |
       v
+------+-------+
|   Splash     |
+------+-------+
       |
       | Proxy Authentication
       v
+------+-------+
| Proxy server |
+------+-------+
       |
       |
       v
+------+-------+
| Target site  |
+--------------+
```

So you'll need to remove this line:

```
request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = self.proxyAuth
```

and properly configure the proxy info:

```
request.meta['splash']['args']['proxy'] = 'proxy info of format: [protocol://][user:password@]proxyhost[:port]'
```

See also: [API reference of Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#render-html) (look for the `proxy` argument)

Comment: thank you very much for this answer！！！！！！which beyond my words，i have working it several days,you saved me！！！and i am also sorry for my poor english

Comment: @陈飞宇 I'm glad it helped. You may accept this answer if it resolved the issue, thus future answerers won't try spending more time helping, and future help seekers might find the solution more easily.